# change all keywords in collection, removing dots from the namespace and replacing with a dash

Tags: clojure

How can I map a function over a vector of maps (which also contain vectors of maps) to remove all dots from keyword namespaces?

So, given:

```
[{:my.dotted/namespace "FOO"}
 {:my.nested/vec [{:another.dotted/namespace "BAR"
                   :and.another/one "FIZ"}]}]
```

becomes:

```
[{:my-dotted/namespace "FOO"}
 {:my-nested/vec [{:another-dotted/namespace "BAR"
                   :and-another/one "FIZ"}]}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [clojure.walk](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html)!

You can traverse the entire data structure and apply a transforming function (`transform-map` in my version) to all the sub-forms that switches a map's keys (here, with `dotted->dashed`) when it encounters one.

```
(require '[clojure
           [walk :as walk]
           [string :as str]])

(defn remove-dots-from-keys
  [data]
  (let [dotted->dashed #(-> % str (str/replace "." "-") (subs 1) keyword)
        transform-map (fn [form]
                        (if (map? form)
                          (reduce-kv (fn [acc k v] (assoc acc (dotted->dashed k) v)) {} form)
                          form))]
    (walk/postwalk transform-map data)))
```

Comment: Thanks that is absolutely what I need - I will remember 'walk'.

Answer (score 4):

I'm partial to [`clojure.walk`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html) for these sort of jobs. The basic idea is to create functions that perform the replacement you want if given a value that should be replaced, else returns the argument. Then you hand that function and a structure to `postwalk` (or `prewalk`) and it walks the data structure for you, replacing each value with the return value of the function on it.

```
(ns replace-keywords
  (:require [clojure.walk :refer [postwalk]]
            [clojure.string :refer [join]]))

(defn dash-keyword [k]
  (when (keyword? k)
    (->> k
      str
      (map (some-fn {\. \-} identity))
       rest
       join
       keyword)))

(dash-keyword :foo.bar/baz)
;; => :foo-bar/baz


(defonce nested [ {:my-dotted/namespace "FOO"}
                  {:my-nested/vec [ {:another-dotted/namespace "BAR"
                                     :and-another/one "FIZ"} ]}])

(postwalk (some-fn dash-keyword identity) nested)
;; =>[{:my-dotted/namespace "FOO"}
;;    {:my-nested/vec [{:another-dotted/namespace "BAR", 
;;                     :and-another/one "FIZ"}]}]
```

Twice here I use the combination of `some-fn` with a function that returns a replacement or `nil`, which can be a nice way to combine several "replacement rules" - if none of the earlier ones fire then `identity` will be the first to return a non-`nil` value and the argument won't be changed.

Answer (score 4):

This problem can also be solved without `clojure.walk`:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(defn dot->dash [maps]
  (mapv #(into {} (for [[k v] %]
                    [(keyword (str/replace (namespace k) "." "-") (name k))
                     (if (vector? v) (dot->dash v) v)]))
        maps))
```

Example:

```
(dot->dash [{:my.dotted/namespace "FOO"}
            {:my.nested/vec [{:another.dotted/namespace "BAR"
                              :and.another/one "FIZ"}]}])
;=> [{:my-dotted/namespace "FOO"}
;    {:my-nested/vec [{:another-dotted/namespace "BAR"
;                      :and-another/one "FIZ"}]}]
```